# Rails 4 .where.not

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
pry(main)> Loan.joins(:statistics).where(state: <some states>).where.not(statistics: {state: <some other states>}).order(created_at: "desc").last.statistics.map(&:state)

2015-09-21 20:53:54,423|65310|DEBUG|development| -   Loan Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `loans`.* FROM `loans` INNER JOIN `statistics` ON `statistics`.`loan_id` = `loans`.`id` WHERE `loans`.`state` IN ('started', 'pending_declined') AND (`statistics`.`state` NOT IN ('prequalified', 'conditionally_approved', '4506t_results_uploaded', 'customer_forms_uploaded', 'ready_for_etran', 'etran_verified', 'forms_to_be_verified', 'forms_verified', 'credit_memo_entered', 'loandoc_generated', 'loandoc_completed', 'loandoc_customer_received_need_signatures', 'signatures_checked_and_uploaded', 'boarded'))  ORDER BY `loans`.`created_at` ASC LIMIT 1
2015-09-21 20:53:54,426|65310|DEBUG|development| -   Statistic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `statistics`.* FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`loan_id` = 97
=> ["started", "prequalified", "conditionally_approved", "customer_forms_uploaded", "ready_for_etran", "pending_declined"]
```

So, maybe I'm not understanding what's going on here... I'm asking SQL to find me some Loans where their Statistics **do not** contain certain values. In this example, I'm saying to leave out any loans with a Statistic of `prequalified`, but, as you can see from the print out, the Loan#statistics does have `prequalified`, along with several other states I'd like to leave out.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I've been fighting with it for hours, and my head is spinning at this point.

Answer (score 0):

With that ActiveRecord query, you've:

- First, found a set of loans
- next, ordered by created_at
- then, used last to find limit to 1 result, finding the oldest of the set

So, you have an instance of Loan.

Since you called #statistics on the method, I can infer that loan `has_many :statistics`, and you've found all statistics that holds a foreign key value that matches the instance of Loan that you found.  Now you have set of statistics.

For the set of statistics, you've mapped them to the `map` attribute.

Since you've already joined the statistics try removing `.last.statistics` from your query. User map on the result set to its state.  Also, consider using [#includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) or #select.

Answer (score 0):

It because you use last.statistics. It means the result on loan object will be joined with statistics whereas you have created condition before.
Look at your last result query:

```
Statistic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `statistics`.* FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`loan_id` = 97
```

remove your last.statistics

```
Loan.joins(:statistics).where(state: <some states>).where.not(statistics: {state: <some other states>}).order(created_at: "desc").map(&:state)
```

or 
if you want to add condition to determine some loans that you need in before `map(&state)`

```
Loan.joins(:statistics).where(state: <some states>).where.not(statistics: {state: <some other states>}).where("loans.id IN (97)").order(created_at: "desc")
```

Answer (score 0):

You query returns product of `Loan` and `Statistic` so it still returns `Loan` records that have **some** `Statistic` that does not have state you specified.

If you only want `Loan` that has no `Statistic` on those states at all you probably want your SQL to be something along this line:

```
SELECT loans.*,
  FROM loans
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT statistics.loan_id, COUNT(*) count
    FROM quotes
    WHERE statistics.state IN ('prequalified', 'conditionally_approved')
      GROUP BY statistics.loan_id
  ) statistics
ON statistics.loan_id = loans.id
WHERE loans.state IN ('started', 'pending_declined') 
AND statistics.count IS NULL;
```

My SQLfu is not what I'd be proud of so this might not be the most optimised query ever but it should get the result you expect.

You could convert that to `ActiveRecord` query interface but unfortunately subquery and `LEFT JOIN` are not really supported, at least not in the way that we going to use it will be something like this:

```
join_query = <<SQL
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT statistics.loan_id, COUNT(*) AS count 
     FROM statistics 
     WHERE statistics.state IN (<<state>>)
   ) statistics ON loans.id = statistics.loan_id
SQL

Loan
  .joins(join_query)
  .where(statistics: { count: null })
  .where(state: <<somestate>>)
  .order(created_at: :desc)
```

The `<<SQL ... SQL` is [Heredoc](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents) by the way if you're not familiar with it.